# check for undefined or null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking if the value of cookie is undefined or null but weirdly this  does not really work

Here's what I tried

```
function check(val){
  if($.cookie(val) === "undefined" || $.cookie(val) === "null"){
     return "1";
  }
     return $.cookie(val);
}
```

So even if my cookie has value null it would print out null instead of 1

Comment: can you be more specific when you say "it doesn't work"? What error do you get on the console output? Have you tried trace debugging the javascript?

Comment: i have already mentioned that above

Comment: no actually....you haven't. What doesn't work....what is the error....have you tried trace debugging?

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are using quotes. In other words, `"undefined" === undefined` is false.

```
if($.cookie(val) === undefined || $.cookie(val) === null){ //this would be more apropriate
```

Comment: that would still return null instead of 1

Comment: @user4142365 that *would* is confusing me in your sentence. Have you tested it? Because it **would** return '1' instead of null. If it **does** return null instead of '1', **could** you make an example? Because it **should** work.

Comment: sorry i had a typo in my code. I was checking for typeof .. Works now. thanks @travis  & karl

Answer (score 0):

Please check if jquery cookie library is included , this is the most general cause.